# TypeScript error: Property does not exist - although it is there

Tags: typescript

I have a React app with TypeScript. This is a Redux selector function:

```
export const calendarImagesSelector = (state: AppState): Content[] =>

    Object.values(state.entities.content.byId)

        .filter((selectedImage) => selectedImage.type === 'image' && selectedImage?.imageInformation?.src)

        .map((image: Content) => image.imageInformation.src);
```

I get the error `Property 'imageInformation' does not exist on type 'Content'.`

But looking into the `Content` type, I think it is there:

```
export type Content = ImageContent | TextContent;

export interface ImageContent extends BaseContent {
    type: ContentTypes.IMAGE;
    path: string;
    rotation: number;
    imageInformation?: ProductImage;
}

export interface TextContent extends BaseContent {
    type: ContentTypes.TEXT;
    fontSize: number;
    horizontalJustification: HorizontalJustification;
    verticalJustification: VerticalJustification;
    fontFamily: string;
    color: CMYK;
    textContent: string;
    rotation: number;
    displayAlign?: string;
    lineHeight?: string;
    originalTop?: string;
    readOnly?: string;
    notes?: string[];
}
```

Only possible solution I found is to say `.map((image: any) => ...);`

But of course that I don't want.

Including `imageInformation` in `TextContent` also does not help.

Because then it will give another error:
`Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'Content[]'.`

Comment: if you're using unions, you will need to provide the type when you want to access a property. ImageContent may have a `imageInformation`, but TextContent probably doesn't.

Comment: what are the properties of interface TextContent ?

Comment: I believe that because imageInformation is an optional property, so you should every time check if it is exists

Comment: No unfortunately it has nothing to do with the prop being optional